# Discord SDK Terminates Unity Editor when Discord is not running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, discord

This question doesn't really contain any code...

I Added the Discord SDK to my project and every time I run the game, it Closes the Unity Editor.
Is there a way to stop the Discord SDK from terminating the Editor?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EliasV you need Discord app running when trying to launch the game in Editor.

```
/*
    Grab that Client ID from earlier
    Discord.CreateFlags.Default will require Discord to be running for the game to work
    If Discord is not running, it will:
    1. Close your game
    2. Open Discord
    3. Attempt to re-open your game
    Step 3 will fail when running directly from the Unity editor
    Therefore, always keep Discord running during tests, or use Discord.CreateFlags.NoRequireDiscord
*/
```

https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/sdk-starter-guide

Answer (score 0):

For init, you can change the `Discord.CreateFlags.Default` to `Discord.CreateFlags.NoRequireDiscord`.

**Or**, you can use #if to check for Unity Editor to `NoRequireDiscord` - else, use the `Default` one!